# How does data compression relate to the ordinary meaning of “compression”?

Tags: data-compression

When I think about "compressing" outside computers I can think about a compressed car which has become a metal rectangle.

- It doesn't have *less redundancy* because it has everything it had before, just compressed and destroyed (data loss)
- It's not *delivered more efficiently* because it's destroyed and isn't restorable by any technology I know of

Perhaps the very terminology of "compression" is just misleading; is there a CS theory in which an alternative term was suggested and if so what is this term?

Comment: Compression is literally the idea of "compressing" something into something "smaller". In CS terms, it means to take an object that stores up a lot of memory, and creating a smaller object that needs less memory, but with the same information (or in some cases with less information, but significantly less memory)

Comment: I think its best to think of compression as a shelf that takes up a lot of space in your room, but you can take it apart to move it around easier. This way, when you take it apart - it will take up less space, but the effect is reversible when you need to use it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to just be a misunderstanding of an English word.

Comment: No, “compress” in English does not imply that something is destroyed. It just means that it takes less space.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' even by your definition here in the comments `It just means that it takes less space` ; how does it has to do anything with "reducing redundancy"? If you create a smaller car, too small for the road, you didn't really eliminate any redundancy.

Comment: If you don't understand the relationship between taking less space and reducing redundancy, this is a computer science question. But it's not the question you asked.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I think it's not about **understanding** it's about the fact that there isn't any such **necessary** connection.

Answer (score 3):

The ordinary meaning of “compression” is to make something smaller. The meaning of “compression” in computer science is also to make something smaller.

To compress data means to make it take less space. Removing redundancy is a *method* for compressing, it isn't the definition of “compression”. The reason it's often said removing redundancy allows data to be compressed comes from the intuition of *[information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information)*. A piece of data has a certain information content. Computer science (a branch of which is called [informatics](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/informatics)) studies information and its representation. If there are different ways to convey the same information through data, i.e. different data representations for the same information, a compression process tries to find a way to represent the data that is smaller than the original representation. Since the compressed representation is smaller than the original representation, but it has the same information content, in some sense, the original data had parts that were superfluous.

This intuition is not completely precise. Strictly speaking, the superfluous parts were not necessarily redundant in the sense of repeating information from the non-superfluous parts. They were, however, redundant in the broader sense of not being necessary. Furthermore, it is not necessarily possible to identify specific parts that are redundant. There is no general rule that compression has to look for redundant parts: it's just one way to do it, which often works. **Redundancy is a technique, not the definition**.

“Delivering more efficiently” is not related to the science of compression at all. If a system has an efficiency bottleneck that is due to the size of the data (typically transmission costs), then reducing the size of the data through compression makes the system more efficient. **It is not always the case that compression makes delivery more efficient**. There are systems where the processing time spent compressing and decompressing is larger than the transmission time saved by compression.

Part of the question is due to a misconception about English: that “compressing” something somehow implies destroying it. It is actually rare that compressing something destroys it. For example, from the [Cambridge Dictionary online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compress):

> to press something into a smaller space:
>
> > Firmly compress the soil in the pot so that the plant is secure.
> > compressed air

> to make information, a piece of writing, etc. shorter:
>
> > The course compresses two year's training into six intensive months.
> > I managed to compress ten pages of notes into four paragraphs.

From [an Oxford dictionary via Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/compress):

> 1   Flatten by pressure; squeeze or press.
>
> > ‘the skirt can be folded and compressed into a relatively small bag’
>
> 1.2   Squeeze or press (two things) together.
>
> > ‘Viola compressed her lips together grimly’
>
> 1.3   Express in a shorter form; abridge.
>
> > ‘in this chapter we compress into summary form the main findings’

(I included all the given definitions and examples for “compress” + noun, excluding technical meanings.) Note that none of them necessarily require anything to be destroyed. Note also that the meaning of expressing information in a shorter way is not related to computer science; it predates computers.

On a final note, data compression *can* destroy some information. Compression is called ***[lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression)*** if it allows the recovery of the original and ***[lossy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression)*** otherwise. Lossy compression removes some information from the data, whereas lossless compression can be said to only remove redundancy (but it can be well-hidden redundancy).